# How do I add a string to the beginning of the name of a collection of files in another directory using shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bunch of .xml files in the folder project/reports. From the "project" folder, I need to prepend the string "TEST-" to every .xml file in the "reports" folder. I know each of the .xml files will start with the same string, and end with .xml, but I don't know the middle. How do I do this?

ie. Original file: constantfilename.xml, New file: TEST-constantfilename.xml

I can't hardcode the names of the test themselves, it just needs to be able to add the string to all files in the folder with the extension .xml. I have seen a lot of methods for renaming the files in the current folder like this:

```
for f in *.xml
do
    mv "$f" "TEST-$f"
done
```

but I don't understand how I can apply this when I need to change them from another directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And before anyone asks, no I cannot just navigate to that folder, it has to be from the "project" folder.

Comment: Would it be an option to run the script under Zsh instead of bash? In this case, it would be simply `mv $f $f:h/TEST-$f:t` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following one-liner (assuming you're on the project folder):

`ls reports/*xml | awk -F '/' '{print "mv "$0" "$1"/TEST-"$2}' | sh`

Is not as clean as yours, but it should give the same result.

Comment: Could you possibly explain that? What does awk do?

Comment: Sure. The `ls` creates a list of files, and the `|` symbol sends that list to `awk`, which in this case is used as a text processing tool. The `print` command assembles the output, and the `sh` executes it. If you're curious, remove the `| sh` and see what is printed on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of googling I ended up doing this. It looks for the string constant I know is at the front of my file and replaces it with TEST-constant.

```
for f in project/reports/*.xml
do
    a="$(echo $f | sed s/constant/TEST-constant/)"
    mv "$f" "$a"
done
```